# magento showing 403 forbidden error for sub domain

Tags: .htaccess, magento, e-commerce, http-status-code-403, magento-1.9.1

I have a magento multi store hosting. There hosted around 6 websites. Now I need to create another store using my sub domain. I created website, store and store view in magento back end and edited htaccess file. suppose my sub domain is abc.domain.in, this is my htaccess code,

```
SetEnvIf Host www\.abc\.domain\.in MAGE_RUN_CODE=abc_domain_in
SetEnvIf Host www\.abc\.domain\.in MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^abc\.domain\.in MAGE_RUN_CODE=abc_domain_in
SetEnvIf Host ^abc\.domain\.in MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

And I changed base url for secured and unsecured in system --> configuration. But if I go to my website it shows 403 forbidden. It says

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server. Additionally, a
>   500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an
>   ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Why is it so?? Any body can help me?

Comment: Why the point after abc isn't backslashed like others?

Comment: should it be like this???
`^abc\.domain\.in MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website`

Comment: @hakkim, Dear, have you get the answer for this?

Comment: Yeah.. I have fixed it.. But I don't remember how I fixed it.. But one thing I am sure... That was some issues related to the basics of multi store adding of magento..